# User to User Messaging with Facebook API

Tags: facebook, curl, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

I am trying to write an application that allows the user to authenticate via Facebook and then allows the user to send messages to their contacts through my platform, but the documentation doesn't seem to indicate any way of doing so. I see where the documentation for Web allows a pop-up share dialog, but I want a pure UI if possible that, after authenticating with Facebook, doesn't use Facebook's UI anymore.

Ideally, I'd like to be able to send the messages from the server instead of through the JavaScript API.

Is this possible?

Comment: No, that is not possible. There is no way to send user-to-user messages via API, the _only_ way is to use the Send dialog to let the user actively perform such an action themselves.

Answer (score 0):

The [Send Dialog](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/reference/send-dialog/) is the only way to send messages from User to User. You cannot send messages with the API, each message has to be written and committed by the user.

Btw, you do not need authorization to use the Send Dialog, just the JavaScript SDK.